# What is special about __func__() functions in python 2.7

Tags: python, class, methods, private

in Python 2.7 one can created private members of a class by preceding them with '__'

```
     >>> class Test:
    def __f():
        print 'hi'


>>> ob=Test()
>>> ob.__f()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    ob.__f()
AttributeError: Test instance has no attribute '__f'
```

In python one can define a function like `f__(x)` also. Then why isn't a function defined as

```
__f__(x)
```

not treated private?

```
>>> class Test2:
    def __f__(self):
        print 'hi'


>>> ob2=Test2()
>>> ob2.__f__()
hi
```

So how exactly are `__f__()` different from f()?

Comment: Because name mangling does not apply for variables with more than one trailing underscore.

Comment: What exactly are the special features of functions like __f__() when compared to just f()

Comment: They're just special names for builtin functions by convention. The language has shortcuts for a lot of them. For example, you can use the bracket notation `a[0]` instead of writing `a.__getitem__(0)`.